# Ubuntu freezing after waking up

Tags: 14.04, suspend, freeze

(Yes, I am back to Ubuntu. I hope you guys make a thing that fixes this.)
Ubuntu 14.04.1 (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) is freezing after waking up from suspend. It doesn't freeze for a few seconds, then the buttons freeze and then the cursor freezes. Going to terminal doesn't do anything.

Also, nvidia drivers doesn't do anything.
The only solution is upgrade to 14.10, but I want to stay on 14.04.

Also clicking to install the Ubuntu YouTube app in Ubuntu kylin FREEZES Ubuntu too.
What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome back! Those are most likely two independent issues. Per the site policy on [how to ask good questions](/help/how-to-ask), it would be better if you move the YouTube app issue to a new question.

Comment: I solved the problem by downgrading to kernel 5.4.0.
Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310622/downgrade-to-kernel-5-4-0-because-kernel-5-8-45-doesnt-like-my-bluetooth-contro

Answer (score 0):

maybe i'm wrong, but i also got my system freezed after a suspend; so i had to hard-Power-off it (On/Off-button pushed > 4s).
The only reason i could find was the newly added boot-option at the grub command line:

*acpi_osi=Linux*.

After i removed it (plus *sudo update-grub2*), the suspend / resume behaviour is now ok again.

Kubuntu 12.04 (LTS) with dist-upgrade to Trusty Tahr 14.04.1 (LTS) on a Lenovo T500

Hope this helps maybe

Comment: I will try. Hope this doesnt break my ubuntu beacuse i just installed it, Well, what really happens is it gets frozen for a minute, then it unfreezes, i enter my password then in the top left corner i get a system error that dissapears after 1 second and it becomes stuck on the background with cursor. EDIT: Nevermind, im already upgrading to ubuntu 14.10