# Downgrade to kernel 5.4.0 because kernel 5.8.45 doesn't like my bluetooth controller

Tags: 20.04, kernel, updates, bluetooth, downgrade

I had no bluetooth issues with kernel 5.4.XX until I updated to kernel 5.8.0.
I can't select 5.4.XX from Grub, is not there.

If I type `dpkg --list | grep linux-image | grep ^ii` on the terminal that's the result:

```
ii  linux-image-5.8.0-38-generic               5.8.0-38.43~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.8.0-40-generic               5.8.0-40.45~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04              5.8.0.40.45~20.04.25                  amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

How can I downgrade to the latest kernel 5.4.xx again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

This will install the latest `5.4` Ubuntu kernel.

Then reboot and select a `5.4` kernel in advanced options of grub menu.

Then remove the `5.8` kernel packages including `headers`, `modules` and `modules-extra`

Comment: How do I remove `5.8` kernel?

Comment: Remove the kernel packages using synaptic or `apt remove`

Comment: I never removed a kernel and I don't want to make a mess. Should I type `sudo apt remove linux-image-5.8.0-38-generic`?

Comment: This is correct. But it is better to remove first ` sudo apt remove linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-38-generic linux-modules-5.8.0-38-generic`. The same with headers.

Comment: Check the installed packages the same as you did, but not `linux-image`, but `linux` pattern.

Comment: What about Linux-images? Should I remove that packages as well?

Comment: First remove modules, then images and headers.

Comment: I did it as you said, then restarted with my finger crossed. Everything went fine but I can still see 5.8.xx if I type `dpkg --list | grep linux-` in the terminal

Comment: I am doing this almost every day ;-)

Comment: Look if they are installed `ii`. If not, then it's OK.

Comment: `ii  linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48
ii  linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-40`

Comment: So remove the headers too. They won't cause harm, but they will get update and occupy space.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PyKcmLd thanks a lot!

Comment: All looks great